# Stop browser from announcing AdBlock

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, adblock

Visiting [this](https://www.whatismybrowser.com) website tells me that my browser announces that it it using AdBlock. Can I stop my browser from announcing that it uses it?

Comment: The browser doesn't announce what extensions it has installed. That's very poor phrasing from that website. Looking into the code of the site it merely checks whether an "ad element" is hidden:

```js
"none" == WIMB_UTIL.get_style(advert_id, "display") ? !0 : !1
```

Comment: I sent them a message via their contact form now asking them to correct this false claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop web sites from knowing you use an adblock tool by installing something like [Anti-Adblock Killer](https://github.com/reek/anti-adblock-killer), which comes as a UserScript. So you will need:

- A script manager, like [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox, or Tampermonkey for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo), [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/tampermonkey-beta/) or [Safari](https://safari.tampermonkey.net/tampermonkey.safariextz).
- Install the Anti-Ablock Killer.
- Then subscribe to a [filter list](http://reek.github.io/anti-adblock-killer/#filterlist).

Comment: In the OP website, Ad Blocker IS still a detected addon but with Adblock Killer I am still able to browse sites such as Wired with Adblock Plus enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a modern content blocker like uBlock Origin or AdGuard, you don't need to install any additional extension or script. When you find a site that tells you to disable your adblocker, just click on the extension button to report it.